# Converting multiple CSVs into xls or xlsx and applying a format to them

Tags: python, vba, batch-file, excel

I have a large excel file that is used to aggregate tracking for issues across multiple clients and I need to divide it into smaller files based on the clients.

Here's what I've got so far: I've built a **python** script that divides the file into the appropriate client-specific files and applies the correct header row to all of them, but it produces CSVs which are ugly. My boss wants to apply some formatting, so what I need to do is (for all CSVs in the directory):

1. convert each file from CSV to .xls (or .xlsx) so it will hold the formatting
2. Auto-fit column widths
3. Make the first row bold (and perhaps apply a color to the row)

So far I'm guessing I can probably do this with either [pyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) or [pyExcelerator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyExcelerator), but considering how minimal the changes I'm looking to make are it may be easier to do this as a VB script or a macro or something, but I don't really know those tools.

Comment: If you've already worked with Excel in VBScript, then it would be a no-brainer to do the rest in VBScript.  However, since you apparently haven't, it's a tough call which would be easier.  One thing I can tell you:  If you are going to stick with Python, please forget about pyExcelerator.  Use xlwt instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `VBA`

Here's a quick macro to loop thriugh a folder of csv's open, apply autofit and save as `.xlsx`

Note:

1. It utilises early binding, therefore requires a reference to the Scripting Runtime. Can easily be altered to late binding if you prefer.
2. For clarity I have ommitted error handling and various speed optimisations. Whether it's safe enough or fast enough will depend on your intended use and number and size of files.

---

```
Sub FormatCSVs()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim pth As String
    Dim fl As File
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    pth = "C:\Test" ' <-- replace with your path, or add a folder selection dialog>
    For Each fl In fso.GetFolder(pth).Files
       If StrComp(fso.GetExtensionName(fl.Path), "csv", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fl.Path)
            With wb.Sheets(1)
                .UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
                .Rows(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End With
            wb.SaveAs pth & "\" & fso.GetBaseName(fl.Path), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
               ' or use xlExcel8 for .xls
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next
    
    Set fl = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but can you elaborate on how to run this? I crated a new workbook in the directory and dropped this code into a macro (I think/I hope?), but when I try to run it I get the following: "Compile error: User-defined type not defined." The line 'fso AS FileSystemObject' is highlighted, so I'm guessing I'm missing a dependency or need to load a library or something.

Comment: You need to add a reference.  From `Tools` menu select `References`.  Scroll down the list to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` tick it and select OK

Comment: You're a beautiful person, Chris. It looks like the script has trouble renaming files as '.xlsx' that have a '.' somewhere in the filename, but otherwise this totally works. Thanks!

PS: If you could show me how to make the header row bold and/or apply a highlight color to that row, that would be extra special.

Comment: @David I added some formatting code.  A ggod way to find how to do things like this in Excel is to use the macro recorder while doing the actions yourself.  This will tell you what properties to use, like `.Interior`